# Is there a way to bundle two installers in one?(especially for python programs)

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyinstaller, espeak

I'm trying to create a program using text-to-speech in python and want to create a windows application out of it. I'm trying to **bundle the software with the espeak text to speech engine** to provide the users with more voices and languages. Looking for a method to **bundle the espeak installer with my own program into a single installer**. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to include another .exe or .msi file inside your bundled Pyinstaller application? Or actually combine them together, so there is only *one* installer that you need to run which installs both programs?

Comment: Yes, I wanna combine them, so that one installer initiates to installs.(Kind of like how some games give an option of installing DirectX and VS redistributables with their installers)